# Uncaught ReferenceError: MasterSlider is not defined

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I'm using Master Slider in Wordpress and it doesn't work. Instead of to looks like this :

http://evolutiongraph.fr/chevereto/images/2014/07/31/aLq1R.jpg

I have an error and it looks like this :

http://evolutiongraph.fr/chevereto/images/2014/07/31/mMan8.jpg

Could anyone help me please ?

```
<script>
    (function ( $ ) {
        "use strict";

        $(function () {
            var masterslider_fc40 = new MasterSlider();

            // slider controls

            // slider setup
            masterslider_fc40.setup("MS53dab8245fc40", {
                    width           : 1920,
                    height          : 500,
                    space           : 0,
                    start           : 1,
                    grabCursor      : true,
                    swipe           : true,
                    mouse           : true,
                    layout          : "fullwidth", 
                    wheel           : false,
                    autoplay        : false,
                    instantStartLayers:false,
                    loop            : false,
                    shuffle         : false,
                    preload         : 0,
                    heightLimit     : true,
                    autoHeight      : false,
                    smoothHeight    : true,
                    endPause        : false,
                    overPause       : true,
                    fillMode        : "fill", 
                    centerControls  : true,
                    layersMode      : "center", 
                    hideLayers      : false, 
                    fullscreenMargin: 0,
                    speed           : 20, 
                    dir             : "h", 
                    parallaxMode    : 'swipe',
                    view            : "basic"
            });


            $("head").append( "<link rel='stylesheet' id='ms-fonts'  href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2:600,regular|Open+Sans:300' type='text/css' media='all' />" );

            window.masterslider_instances = window.masterslider_instances || {};
            window.masterslider_instances["2_fc40"] = masterslider_fc40;
         });

    })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code and error message in your post. Thank you.

Comment: Well, given the code you posted, you are not defining `MasterSlider` anywhere. That's why you get the error.

Comment: It's not my code, but the code generated by the plugin :/

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, chances are that you forgot to add `wp_footer()` function to footer.php so the slider's JavaScript files are not rendered and resulting you with this error.